# Can't serve website due to _BundleGraph.default assertion error

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have almost zero background in Node.js, and I was trying to serve locally a website via the command:

```
parcel serve index.html --port 3001
```

However, I get the following error:

```
 Build failed.

Error: The expression evaluated to a falsy value:

  (0, _assert().default)(bundleGraph instanceof _BundleGraph.default)


  AssertionError [ERR_ASSERTION]: The expression evaluated to a falsy value:
  
    (0, _assert().default)(bundleGraph instanceof _BundleGraph.default)
  
      at Object.runPackage (/home/tommaso/repos/showcase-hn-comments-semantic-search/node_modules/parcel/node_modules/@parcel/core/lib/worker.js:176:25)
      at Child.handleRequest (/home/tommaso/repos/showcase-hn-comments-semantic-search/node_modules/@parcel/workers/lib/child.js:216:36)
      at Child.messageListener (/home/tommaso/repos/showcase-hn-comments-semantic-search/node_modules/@parcel/workers/lib/child.js:108:19)
      at ThreadsChild.onMessage (/home/tommaso/repos/showcase-hn-comments-semantic-search/node_modules/@parcel/workers/lib/child.js:84:12)
      at ThreadsChild.handleMessage (/home/tommaso/repos/showcase-hn-comments-semantic-search/node_modules/@parcel/workers/lib/threads/ThreadsChild.js:59:10)
      at MessagePort.<anonymous> (/home/tommaso/repos/showcase-hn-comments-semantic-search/node_modules/@parcel/workers/lib/threads/ThreadsChild.js:53:61)
      at MessagePort.[nodejs.internal.kHybridDispatch] (node:internal/event_target:562:20)
      at MessagePort.exports.emitMessage (node:internal/per_context/messageport:23:28)
```

Any idea on how I can debug/figure out what is it? Coming from Python, my first step was placing a debugger; line before the assertion. However it is getting ignored.